# Is writing fiction a form of lie?

Tags: lying

Assalamualaikum
I'm a Muslim girl, who is interested in writing stories. I've written a few stories and many people, including my parents, have complimented me and have encouraged me to publish them on sites . But the problem is that, I only write fiction stories. I don't want it to become my profession or anything.. And i don't want to make money or fame out of it. All I want is to write. But is fiction stories allowed in islam? And what I mean by 'fiction' is magic and adventures. Like a fairy tale or something.. Is it against Islam in doing so? I mean isn't it a form of lie as long as I'm writing something that's unreal. 
Is it still considered as a lie even if it has a moral in it?
Please help in answering.
Jazakallah khair

Answer (score 0):

Fiction is expression of ones imagination. Lying is deliberately steaking false statement and convincing others that it is true. As long as readers know that its fiction its not a lie

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/163469/she-is-an-author-who-writes-stories-and-articles-in-english-and-is-asking-about-the-ruling-on-writing-and-receiving-payment-for-it

http://www.understanding-islam.com/is-writing-fiction-forbidden-in-islam/